# QGIS: Using OSgeo4W shell to login to and create a new PostGIS database

Tags: qgis, postgis, database, osgeo4w, shell

I'm trying to create a new database through the OSgeo4W shell, as opposed to loading QGIS and hitting the 'Manage DB' menu to make one an pipe in SQL scripts. I haven't seen any documentation on this specific issue.

I've tried piping in `psql` commands with the `-p` , `-U` and `createdb` commands to login and attempt to make a new database. I haven't had any success so far. I've mainly gotten *connection refused* messages, even though I type in the login information.

I'm not sure what the issue is here, or what I may be forgetting to do.

Shown are a couple attempts:

[image]

Comment: Works for me with `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres databasename`. I get the same error than you if I stop the database service.

Comment: Did you ever install and run the PostgreSQL database service? Service and user management is different in Linux in Windows.